# Restricting the number controls inside a Winform Flow Layout Panel

Tags: c#, winforms, c#-4.0

This is the scenario

I have a Flow layout panel. I add label controls dynamically to this panel. I have set the height and width of this panel during the design time. For instance , say the height is 100 and I have added 4 labels to the panel which occupied about 90. The 5th label has height 25. When I try adding this label to the panel, either the panel height should be adjusted to 90 or should restrict the 5th label being added to the panel.

Need your help in this.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you know about the `Control.Controls` collection? Each control has this property containing all child controls (i.e. `FlowLayoutPanel.Controls` in your case). Like all collections, it contains a `Count` property which can be read to see how many child controls are already in your parent control.

Comment: Is there a way by which you can check if the panel is filled ( i.e , the overflow limit ) ?

Comment: Hi I found the solution. I summed up individual height of all the labels  and checked against the panel height :) If true->add the control, Else->Restrict